# Android-Studio reports autoboxing errors, but still compiles

Tags: java, android

I am calling a Java library from my Android project. Sometimes, I create an object `MyObj(double a, double b)` with `Double`s (as opposed to `double`s). Android-Studio shows them as error and says:

> MyObj(double, double) in MyObj cannot be applied to (Double, Double)

How could that be?

Another weirdness is the following:

> MyOtherObj(String) in MyOtherObj cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Note that it compiles and runs fine. Also, building with gradle in command line (`./gradlew build`) works perfectly. Is there something to do when using a Java library inside an Android-Studio project?

As requested in the comment, here is some of the actual code showing this error:

```java
Mission.MissionItem missionItem = new Mission.MissionItem(
    latLng.getLatitude(),
    latLng.getLongitude())
```

If I replace the first argument by `new Double(3.2)`, the error message becomes:

> expected: Double, actual: new Double(3.2) (java.lang.Double)

Comment: could you please post some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Java was not configured properly. I went to *File > Project Structure... > SDK Location* and ticked the box "Use embedded JDK (recommended)".

Not sure what was wrong with my system install, though, especially because Intellij works like a charm with Java.